# Does checking against Boolean.TRUE/Boolean.FALSE avoid boxing/unboxing?

Tags: java, boolean, boxing, unboxing

Let's say I have a `Map<Integer, Boolean>` and I want to filter out all the integers that have a boolean-value of `true`. Here's some code:

```
for (Map.Entry<Integer, Boolean> e : map.entrySet()){
    if (e.getValue() == true){ // Unboxing here
        // Do something useful...
    }
}
```

In this code, the `Boolean`-object is unboxed every time the if is executed (which might be a problem if the map is really large).

Now, the `Boolean`-class offers constants (`Boolean.TRUE` and `Boolean.FALSE`), which represent the normal boolean values `true` and `false` as an already boxed version (*right?*). So using this code would avoid unboxing *completely*:

```
for (Map.Entry<Integer, Boolean> e : map.entrySet()){
    if (e.getValue() == Boolean.TRUE){ // No Unboxing done (?)
        // Do something useful...
    }
}
```

Am I right about this assumption? Or is it even worse and both values are unboxed to be compared?

Comment: Have you looked at the unboxing code? `booleanValue() { return value; }`, where `value` is a `private final boolean` set in the constructor. In other words, this is a super-fast method that can be inlined if needed. I wouldn't bother trying to optimize it away by hand.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It will work if you used the primitive `boolean` literals to add elements to your map.

When using primitive literals where a reference type is expected, the compiler will use `Boolean#valueOf(..)` implemented as

```
public static Boolean valueOf(boolean b) {
    return (b ? TRUE : FALSE);
}
```

to return a value of type `Boolean`. So you will get the same two `Boolean` objects every time.

If you instead added to the map with

```
new Boolean(true) // or new Boolean(false)
```

it will be a different reference, so comparison with `==` will fail.

---

This does seem like premature optimization.

Comment: It is premature optimization, this was more out of interest than for performance reasons.